# Changes to procedure are not saved when running alter procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

There is a stored procedure in Sql server 2012 called "proc1". I have taken the procedure script then implemented Exception Handling (Begin Try...End Try Begin Catch...End Catch) in to it.

I changed the "Create procedure proc1" statement as "Alter procedure proc1" then executed it. It completed successfully but when I try to get the same procedure script again. I can't find the exception handling part. The code looks like the old stored procedure code.

I am wondering it is possible. Even if I don't have permission then it should return a error message during the "alter procedure proc1" compilation.

Comment: do a sp_helptext 'procname' after the change and see the text within if you have your new code and also see what is the schema of the proc you are altering does it say dbo.procname or something and are you looking at the right schema and also see the database server name sometime we landup changing in one enviornment and look at another in management studio.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't inadvertently create the procedure in the wrong database, and then when you reloaded it from the "intended" database, only the old code was present?

Comment: Refresh the procedure before retrieving the code.

Comment: what is the code in the catch, and you always are able to find the errors in Managment->SQL Server Log

Comment: @DavidW good point! type `USE YourDatabaseName GO`before your create/alter statement. maybe you created in master or somewhere else...

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, When I tried to extract the procedure script through ssms its seems correct but through tsql using either syscomments for sys.sql_modules the script seems old code. However sp_helptext returns the correct code. I am in a bit confusion right now. Which one I have to use in TSQL either sp_helptext or syscomments or sys.sql_modules or information_schema.routines?

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that stored procedures are a part of the database. That means that they behave like any other “normal” objects defined with DDL (Data Definition Language) statements such as tables. Thus:

- Transactions apply to DDL (Data Definition Language) statements including `CREATE PROCEDURE`/`ALTER PROCEDURE`. So if the session you were using to alter the procedure was in a transaction and you never committed that transaction, the changes will be rolled back.
- The content of procedures is part of the database, so restoring a backup of the database will revert not only data but also changes to procedures.

As you said, if there was an error that caused the database to altogether reject your alteration, you should receive an obvious error while trying to execute it and the change will not be made. For example, if there is a syntax error in the `ALTER PROCEDURE` command itself, you will get an error without any of the batch executing at all. Or if your procedure body refers to a nonexistent column of an existent table, Transact-SQL may choose to validate the procedure and reject the change (if the table didn’t exist, it would accept that change and just fail to run the procedure when attempting to execute it later because Transact-SQL is arguably inconsistent with itself that way).